# Change TabItem child StackPanel to Vertical Orientation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to adjust the `Orientation` property of a `StackPanel` that is child to a `TabItem` that is above the `DataTemplate` in the visual tree.

[image: screenshot of needs]

From the attached pic, you can see the WPF form, the XAML, and the visual tree. I'm just not sure how to get to that StackPanel and change it's orientation. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: When you say vertical , do you want to rotate the tabs to show up on left side?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that all I needed to do was define my own Template (and not HeaderTemplate).